# MySQL join through relational table

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I can't seem to find the right way to write this query. I have two entities websites and clients, and a table that relates them through their id fields.

This is a many to many relationship. i.e. a website can have multiple clients and a client can have multiple websites.

I am trying to write a query that returns all the websites with the clients that belong to them. I want to return all the websites even if they have no clients associated with them. Here is the query that I am working with at the moment:

the three tables are ost_sites = websites, ost_site_auth = relational table, ost_clients = clients

```
SELECT 
    ost_sites.site_id, 
    ost_sites.name,
    ost_sites.site_url,
    ost_site_auth.site_id,
    ost_site_auth.client_id 
    ost_clients.client_id,
    CONCAT_WS(" ", ost_clients.lastname, ost_clients.firstname) as name,
FROM ost_sites
LEFT JOIN (ost_site_auth, ost_clients) 
    ON (ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 
        AND ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id)
GROUP BY ost_sites.name
```

I get a result set but it doesn't return all the sites, and all of the rows don't have clients associated with them.

Thanks so much for any help!

### Edit:

Here are the columns for the tables:

ost_site

```
site_id |    name    | site_url
1          facebook    facebook.com
2          twitter     twitter.com
3          tubmblr     tumblr.com
4          google      google.com
```

ost_site_auth

(notice no site_id = 3 in auth list)

```
id |   site_id    | client_id
1        1             1
2        1             2
3        2             1 
4        2             2
5        4             1
6        4             4
```

ost_client

```
client_id  |  firstname  |  lastname
1              wilma         flintstone
2              bam           bam
3              fred          flintstone
4              barney        rubble
```

expected output:

```
site_id |    name    |    site_url    |      client_name     |
1          facebook    facebook.com        wilma flintstone
1          facebook    facebook.com        bam bam
2          twitter     twitter.com         wilma flintstone
2          twitter     twitter.com         bam bam
4          google      google.com          wilma flintstone
4          google      google.com          barney rubble
3          tumblr      tumlr.com           NULL
```

Comment: What result _do_ you get from this query? Could you post an example output? Or a part of your data?

Comment: I'll edit the post with general data, but I can't put in specific data as names and websites pertain to my job.

Comment: okay... four queries here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58974/6/0

Comment: I just edited the post let me know if that is a bit clearer

Comment: and I even added 5th query at the top of this link.... http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/58974/7/0 -->  From your example... you just want to use a `left outer join`.  I'm not sure how the first query I initially suggested doesn't fit what you want...?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a `GROUP BY` clause is inappropriate. Perhaps you meant to include the `DISTINCT` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your join looks a bit off... try this

```
SELECT 
    ost_sites.site_id, 
    ost_sites.name,
    ost_sites.site_url,
    ost_site_auth.site_id,
    ost_site_auth.client_id 
    ost_clients.client_id,
    CONCAT_WS(" ", ost_clients.lastname, ost_clients.firstname) as name

FROM ost_sites

LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_site_auth 
    ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_clients
    ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

ORDER BY ost_sites.name
```

---

Let me try to explain this a little for you...

- We start with the `ost_sites` table and we want *all* the results from that regardless of if anything matches in the other tables.
- Then, we do a `left outer join` to the table `ost_site_auth`.  That means that if something from `ost_site_auth` does not match something in `ost_sites`, it will not be returned.  However, something in `ost_sites` that doesn't match something in `ost_site_auth` will be returned because of the `left outer` part.
- Next, we repeat the `left outer join` for the `ost_clients`.

---

---

Not sure what you want... Let's pretend we have this data represented in the tables:

- Site #1 has no clients
- Site #2 has one client: A
- Site #3 has two clients: B, C
- Site #4 has three clients: D, E, F
- Site #5 has no clients
- Clients G and H have no associated site

**Query One**

```
      SELECT 
          ost_sites.site_id as SITE,   
          ost_clients.client_id as CLIENT

      FROM ost_sites

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id, ost_clients.client_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE     CLIENT 
1        NULL
2        A
3        B
3        C
4        D
4        E
4        F
5        NULL
```

**Query Two**

```
      SELECT 
          ost_sites.site_id as SITE,   
          ost_clients.client_id as CLIENT

      FROM ost_sites

      JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id, ost_clients.client_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE     CLIENT  
2        A
3        B
3        C
4        D
4        E
4        F
```

**Query three**

```
      SELECT 
          ost_sites.site_id as SITE,   
          ost_clients.client_id as CLIENT

      FROM ost_sites

      FULL OUTER JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      FULL OUTER JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id, ost_clients.client_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE     CLIENT  
1        NULL
2        A
3        B
3        C
4        D
4        E
4        F
5        NULL
NULL     G
NULL     H
```

**Query four**

```
      SELECT DISTINCT ost_sites.site_id as SITE 

      FROM ost_sites

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id 
      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE         
2
3
4
```

**Query five**

```
      SELECT 
          ost_sites.site_id as SITE,
          count(ost_clients.client_id) as CLIENT_COUNT

      FROM ost_sites

      JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      GROUP BY ost_sites.site_id 
      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE        CLIENT_COUNT  
2           1
3           2
4           3
```

**Query five**

```
      SELECT 
          ost_sites.site_id as SITE,
          count(ost_clients.client_id) as CLIENT_COUNT

      FROM ost_sites

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_site_auth 
          ON ost_sites.site_id=ost_site_auth.site_id 

      LEFT OUTER JOIN ost_clients
          ON ost_site_auth.client_id=ost_clients.client_id

      GROUP BY ost_sites.site_id 
      ORDER BY ost_sites.site_id
```

That would return (basically)

```
SITE        CLIENT_COUNT  
1           0
2           1
3           2
4           3
5           0
```

Comment: on the second `join` I had accidentally left `and` there instead of changing it to `on`... that has been updated/edited now.

Comment: This works and gives me all of the websites and one client associated with that website (NULL if that website has no clients). I just need it to return multple rows if that website has multiple clients. Maybe I could have query just return all websites with clients and then perform another query to find which ones don't have clients?

Comment: is that what you want?  if you do a straight `join` it will only return things that have matching rows in all three tables.  if you would do a `right outer join` it would go in reverse joining order, so you would get all clients regardless of if they had rows in `ost_site_auth` and then `ost_sites`.  (It's always better to use a `left outer join` because it is more common and therefore easier to visualize/understand.)

Comment: If you want to return everything where it matches and even if it doesn't, you should use the `full outer join` that the other answer is referring to... Where the data matches up, you would get a full row.  But you would also get sites without clients and clients. without sites.

Comment: So you don't want to see sites that do not have any clients?

Comment: This would most likely be the best way to describe the result set I am thinking of. For a site return all of the clients associated with it only if it has at least one client. Then union all of the sites that have no clients. Does that make sense?

Comment: This would give something like site1 => client 1, site1 => client2, site2 => client3, site3 => NULL, site4 => client3, site4 => client2

Comment: query 1 is what I want let me try to run it really quickly.

Comment: Wow that works thanks so much I wish I could upvote your answer more. This whole post is actually really helpful. I tried to do a FULL OUTTER JOIN like you suggested earlier but mysql kept saying there was a syntax error on FULL.

Comment: I was essentially just changing 3 words per query lol... maybe you understand joins a little bit better now?

Comment: Yes I'm sure I'm not the only one that this is helpful to. Thanks agian

Answer (score 0):

Check out

[Full Outer Join in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql)

I think all you really need to do is do the same query as a right outer join as well and union them.